# Unity blocks whenever I try to execute a command line prompt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, command-line, cmd, process

I am trying to execute a command line prompt in unity using C#, I first need to change the directory to `C://Users//HP//Documents` then execute a command that should be under Documents, this is what I have been doing:

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo ("cmd.exe");
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.RedirectStandardInput = true;
var process = Process.Start (proc);    
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C://Users//HP//Documents");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("MyCommandLine");
```

The MyCommandLine should create a text file under Documents, but instead Unity blocks every time I execute the function.
Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cmd.exe process never exits after running "MyCommandLine". Add an "exit" command like this

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
```

Comment: Thanks, it no longuer blocks now but directory is not changing !

Comment: You're using forward slashes rather than backward slashes. You also don't need double slashes when you use the @ sign. Try @"cd C:\Users\HP\Documents".